# Learning Git Hub on Trailhead

Tags: trailhead, git

am I am trying to work through the DX trail on Trailhead. I am stuck on the Github portion. I have installed Git on my local machine as well as Visual Studio Code. I have created the repo and the branch.

Trailhead then tells you to open the README in your repo and make some changes with your text editor. I am totally stuck on how to get VSC to see my GIT Repo and open the file. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Git repository is just a directory with some special tracking in a hidden `.git` directory inside it.

Do `File->Open Folder` in Visual Studio Code and navigate to the location where you created your repository. Select the outermost repository directory (not the `force-app` inner directory , if that has already been created), and open that in Visual Studio Code. You'll get a directory tree where you can navigate the project contents on the left of your VSC window and locate `README.md`.